# Removing LaTeX characters from string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a TeX document like so

```
s = '\textbf{1 + 1} \begin{center} \textbf{some text in here:} \end{center} and \textbf{2} etc'
```

I would like to remove the `\textbf{` and the closing brace `}`

So the final text would look something like this

```
1 + 1 \begin{center} some text in here: \end{center} and 2 etc'
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
import re 

re.sub(r'\textbf{(.*)}', '\\1', s)
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried to solve this problem. Does it work? If not, what does not work?

Comment: One way is to use github.com/alvinwan/texsoup. This is overpowered for the current task, but TexSoup will be useful if your task becomes ever so slightly more complicated (e.g., only replace boldfaced text in `\begin{...}...\end{...}` environments) `soup = TexSoup(r"\textbf{1 + 1} \begin{center} \textbf{some text in here:} \end{center} and \textbf{2} etc"); [sub.replace(sub.args[0]) for sub in soup.find_all('textbf')]; print(soup)` disclaimer: I wrote this lib. also, bad practice to use list comprehension when you don't use the return value

Comment: @alvinwan this is great. thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\\textbf{([^}]*)}
```

Explanations:

You were really close to a working regex: you just had to escape the first `\` (otherwise \t will be interpreted as `tab`) and add the condition to accept all characters inside the curvy braces except the `}` this is done by `[^}]`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qWU3Mf/1/

**OUTPUT:**

```
1 + 1 \begin{center} some text in here: \end{center} and 2 etc
```

**READINGS:**

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: Sorry I deleted my earlier comment as I misread the question! My bad - regex is definitely the correct solution here. (Also deleted my answer)

Comment: its working on the sampled string i have. thank you. Can you please elaborate on the logic you have within the regex

Comment: @Jordan: no prob!

Comment: @dimitris_ps: just edited my post, is it enough for you?